# Update List view from Process callback output instantly C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface, process

i'm trying to update my listview from my callback function that reads the stdout of a process.
i'm doing something like this:

```
process.OutputDataReceived = function();

public void function() {
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((MethodInvoker)() => {
        listview.Items.add(newItem);
    });
}
```

this updates my listview, but only when the process finishes!

i want it to update the list view instantly and i have no idea how and why it's not doing it like this.

thanks.

Comment: So how are you reading from the standard output? Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void StartProcess()
{
   var myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
   {
       UseShellExecute = false,
       FileName = exePath,
       CreateNoWindow = false,
       ErrorDialog = true
   };
   var process = new Process();
   process.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;
   process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
   process.OutputDataReceived += function;
   process.BeginOutputReadLine();
   process.WaitForExit();
}

public void function() 
{
   this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => { listview.Items.add(newItem);}));
}
```